# Unable to resolve the request "site/myuserclassroom" in Yii 1.x

Tags: php, yii, yii-components

I am working on Yii 1.x website locally using a vagrant box, everything seems ok on this when I transfer the files to a staging server I get the following 404 error message:

Unable to resolve the request "site/myuserclassroom"

The filename in question is called 'MyuserClassroomController.php' with the class called 'MyuserClassroomController'

There doesn't seem to be any issues with case sensitive filenames that I can see, but I don't know why Yii isn't loading the page in the same manner as my Vagrant equivalent using the exact same codebase.

Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe your server is configured wrong. Please post some logs and relevant config files.

Comment: so you are going to example.com/site/myuserclassroom or example.com?r=site/myuserclassroom? In that case your going to the controller SiteController and the action myuserclassroom. Unless the site is a module offcourse. However more information would be great. What url do your use, how did you setup your urlManager, etc.

Comment: did you set 'caseSensitive' => false. in your urlManger ?

Comment: Take careful note if Jeroen's comments. The answer  is there.

Comment: My problem is like yours, I change my controller name from MyUserClassRoomController.php to MyuserclassroomController.php (also the name of the class), and it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have `site/myuserclassroom` url, you must define your controller like this: `MyuserclassroomController`. I think this will work.